# attribute binding with Template literals doesn't work in vuejs components?

Tags: vue.js

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/x-template" id="permissions">
    <div>
        <h3 v-bind:data=`haha-${title}` >{{ title }}</h3>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
    <blog-post title="My journey with Vue"></blog-post>
</div>

<script>
    Vue.component('blog-post', {
        props: ['title'],
        template: '#permissions'
    })
</script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app"
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I bind the **data** attribute on h3 to "haha"+ title.

This technique works on regular vue elements, but it doesn't work on vue component. The result is [image]

Why does it happen? How to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:

```js
<h3 v-bind:data="`haha-${title}`">{{ title }}</h3>
```

Attribute values need to be delimited with either `"` or `'`. The `v-bind:` prefix causes Vue to treat the value of the attribute as a JavaScript expression. Within that expression the backticks will be interpreted as you're expecting. You can't just merge the two sets of quotes, they serve different purposes.

Comment: shorthand for `v-bind:data=""` is just `:data=""`. docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html